# The equation number of multi lined formulas

Tags: equations, numbering, multline

I use \multlined command in the equation environment. The equation number is attached at the first line, but I want this number be at the last line of formula. what sould I do.

```
\begin{equation} 
  X_{\alpha\beta} = \begin{multlined}[t] K R R_{\alpha\mu} R_{\beta\nu} g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}J - \nabla^{\sigma}\nabla_{\beta}( J R R_{\alpha\sigma}) \\
- g_{\alpha\beta} \square \mathcal{J} + \frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{\rho}{\sigma} (K R R^{\rho\sigma})+\frac{2}{8}( K R) \end{multlined}
 \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `multline` instead?

```
\begin{multline} 
  X_{\alpha\beta} = K R R_{\alpha\mu} R_{\beta\nu} g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}J - \nabla^{\sigma}\nabla_{\beta}( J R R_{\alpha\sigma}) \\
- g_{\alpha\beta} \square \mathcal{J} + \frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{\rho}{\sigma} (K R R^{\rho\sigma})+\frac{2}{8}( K R) 
 \end{multline}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Why not incorporate  the  1st part into the `multlined` environment? I also used medium sized fractions for fractional coefficients (`\mfrac` from `nccmath`) as I think they look nicer in this context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{multlined}[b] X_{\alpha\beta} = K R R_{\alpha\mu} R_{\beta\nu} g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}J - \nabla^{\sigma}\nabla_{\beta}( J R R_{\alpha\sigma}) \\
- g_{\alpha\beta} \square \mathcal{J} + \mfrac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{\rho}{\sigma} (K R R^{\rho\sigma})+\mfrac{2}{8}( K R) \end{multlined}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added* :
An alignment from the right side is also rather pleasing, in my opinion:

```
  \begin{align}
X_{\alpha\beta} = K R R_{\alpha\mu} R_{\beta\nu} g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\alpha}\nabla_{\beta}J - \nabla^{\sigma}\nabla_{\beta}( J R R_{\alpha\sigma})\notag \\
   {} - g_{\alpha\beta} \square \mathcal{J} + \mfrac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{\rho}{\sigma} (K R R^{\rho\sigma})+\mfrac{2}{8}( K R) 
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Tanx, This is correct too.But what is the difference between using that at the first of line or in the middle?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you. The difference between using what?

Comment: Between using "multlined" command at the first of formula line or at middle of the that (such as what I have written in the question).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand perfectly, but I  used the `[b]` placement specifier to obtain the number on the last line.